# Problems with object JSON conversion

Tags: json, node.js

I have one object (jar), which contains this (by console.log):

```
{ _jar: { store: { idx: { localhost: { '/': { PHPSESSID: Cookie="PHPSESSID=pe1952pk023e7b6d7t9am3kse0; Path=/; hostOnly=true; aAge=18ms; cAge=97ms" } } } } } }
```

I'm trying to store it to MongoDB instance which is ok, but after loading it from there, it's kind of malformed. This simulates it:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jar)));
```

The above outputs this:

```
{ _jar: { store: { idx: [Object] } } }
```

So all of the sudden 'localhost' part got vanished into 'Object'? How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`console.log`](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_log_data) doc says:

> If formatting elements are not found in the first string then
>   util.inspect is used on each argument.

[`util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) doc says:

> Return a string representation of object, which is useful for
>   debugging.
>
> [...]
>
> - depth - tells inspect how many times to recurse while formatting the object. This is useful for inspecting large complicated objects.
>     Defaults to 2. To make it recurse indefinitely pass null.

That is, `console.log(jar)` prints only the first two levels, `_jar` and `store`, and the fields of `store` are printed in short format. That's why the content of `store.idx` is printed as `[Object]`. To print every level, type `util.inspect(jar, { depth: null })`.

Answer (score 1):

That `console.log` formatting, not a JSON.parse problem.

`console.log(jar)` will give you the same output.